# Convert char to int to NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am writing some code to allow users to answer multiple choice questions. So I have an NSArray of values [@"value1", @"value2", ..]

I want to display them as:
A) value1
B) value2

The code I have is

```
for(int i = i; i < [values count]; i = i+1) {
NSString *displayValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:<NEED HELP HERE>];
displayValue = [displayValue stringByAppendingString:@") "];
displayValue = [displayValue stringByAppendingString:[values objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

The question I have is if there is where I have put , how could I convert i to the right ASCII character (A, B, C, etc) and initialize the string with that value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *displayValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",'A'-1+i];
```

and to get the whole string at once, use:

```
NSString *displayValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c) %@",'A'-1+i,
                                                   [values objectAtIndex:i]];
```

(ps. if you `alloc` an object, you must also `release` or `autorelease`, or you will "leak" memory)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`NSString:initWithFormat`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithFormat:) method, along with the [String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943).